# What is the source for the mitzvah of kiruv?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, mitzvah, kiruv-outreach

Is kiruv a mitzvah? 
Is it biblical or rabbinic?
Is there any reason it should supersede other mitzvot?
what are the sources in chazal and halacha relating to kiruv?

related: [Kiruv and halachik compromise](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14629/kiruv-and-halachik-compromise)

Comment: Well IIRC one may be mechalel Shabbos to save a person spiritually as well as physically, so hatzalas nefashos is one place to start looking

Comment: +1 I was just thinking about this question. I know there is a Zohar about it, but that's not necessarily authoritative.

Answer (score 10):

[Rav Yitzchak Berkovits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Berkovits), based on the [Chofetz Chaim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Meir_Kagan)'s introduction to his sefer [Chomas HaDas](http://hebrewbooks.org/41647), compiled [a source sheet](http://www.thejerusalemkollel.com/wp-content/uploads/download/BerkowitzSheets/Bein_Adam_LaChaveiro/12_The_Chiyuv_of_Kiruv.pdf) which explains four basic ideas which obligate kiruv:

1. **Kavod Shamayim** - Honor of Heaven:

   - We are obligated to care about and increase *kavod shamayim* in the world. The ***Chofetz Chaim*** brings a *Midrash* ([Bereishis Rabbah 54:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.54.4?lang=he)) which says the Jewish people were reprimanded for caring more about their animals than the fact that the *Aron HaKodesh* was stolen by the *Pelishtim* ([I Samuel 5:1](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.5.1?lang=bi)). This obligation stems from the *mitzvah* of **Ahavas Hashem**, Loving G-d. The ***Rambam*** (*Sefer HaMitzvos* #3) explains that part of the *mitzvah* is the desire to spread the knowledge of Hashem in the world. This should obligate us to educate those ignorant of the Torah and inspire them to fulfill it.
2. **Arvus** - All Jews are guarantors for each other:

   - As long as others haven't fulfilled their *mitzvah*, there's a lacking in **my** fulfillment of my *mitzvah*. Sometimes it's even better to lessen my own *mitzvah* in order to facilitate others fulfilling theirs (see ***Magen Avraham*** to *Orach Chaim* 658 §12 and 671 §1). This shows how important it is to ensure all the Jews are doing what they are supposed to be doing.
3. **Hashavas Aveidah** - Returning a lost object:

   - The ***Chofetz Chaim*** claims that if the Torah [obligates us to return someone's  lost object](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.22.1?lang=bi&aliyot=0), all the more so should we return their **souls**. This idea is also found in the ***Shelah*** (*Torah Shebekesav Parshas Kedoshim s.v.* שלא לעמוד על דם) and ***Minchas Chinuch*** (#239 §6).
4. **Hakamas HaTorah** - Upholding the fulfillment of the Torah:

   - There's a curse against those who don't uphold the Torah ([Deuteronomy 27:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.27.26?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=he)). The ***Yerushalmi*** (see ***Ramban*** [*ad. loc.*](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Deuteronomy.27.26.1?lang=bi)) explains that this includes making sure those that are ignoring the Torah fulfill it. The ***Chofetz Chaim*** holds that anyone who can influence others to fulfill the Torah and decides not to should be very afraid that this curse not affect them. Those who do inspire others are therefore included in the corresponding blessing for those who uphold the Torah.

The sources I didn't link to are readable in the above source sheet.

Answer (score 8):

[Rav Sheinberg ZS"L](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Pinchas_Scheinberg) said the source is "Kol Yisrael Arevim ZeLaze."

Comment: Did R. Sheinberg himself tell this to you (an anonymous person on the internet)? Did he write this somewhere? Did he say this over in a lecture?

Answer (score 7):

The mitzvah of tochecha(rebuke) and vahavta l'reacha kamocha(loving ones friend) are intertwined and kiruv is a huge mitzvah and it is like saving a life. Rambam (Mitzvos Aseh 3),Minchas Chinuch (Mitzvah 239 Os 4) .The Gemara in Shevous 39 brings the idea from a passuk of areivus(responsible for a community)that not only one has to help individuals but also bring a community closer.

Comment: Sam, is tochecha the same thing as kiruv? would that mean that kiruv would follow the same halachic parameters (such as only doing if you know the person will listen/improve)? Is there a source that pairs kiruv with any of the mitzvot you mention?

Comment: The Rambam in sefer hamtzvos mitzva 3( to love Hashem) he explains kiruv is part of this mitzva because if one really loves someone he will get everyone interested to also love that person.The Ramban explains tochecha and loving ones friend is one concept and the idea is really kiruv to bring the person back to Hashem with love.

Answer (score 5):

There is an Ohr haChaim by the *mitzvah* of *hashavas aveidah* which learns homiletically (*al derech derush*) that returning lost objects to one's friend is an allegory for returning lost Jews to Hashem.

I am not sure how authoritative it is really as a halachic source though.