# Is one obligated to do some kind of Jewish outreach today

Tags: kiruv-outreach, lo-taamod-al-dam-reyecha

Considering the high assimilation / intermarriage rates today, is there an obligation to try to do some kind of outreach according to one's ability (either personally such as shabbat guests or monetarily, i.e. donating to kiruv organizations)

Perhaps from the verse "lo ta'amod al dam re'echa" (Leviticus 19:16) or some other source.

Comment: Can you bring an example? I didn't get what you want. Abyway, "lo ta'amod al dam re'echa" is reffer to rescue someone dying.

Comment: spiritual danger may also be in this category. that's part of the question. examples of outreach - endeavoring to have nonreligious guests or learning on the phone, etc.

Comment: Highly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16281/what-is-the-source-for-the-mitzvah-of-kiruv

Comment: @IsaacMoses Dupe?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm gonna go ahead and say yes.

Comment: that answer just says it is a "big mitzva". my question is whether it is a "must do" type of mitzva such as lulav or like when someone is drowning and only you can save him.